I get negative matrix entries under the evolution by the GKSL equation
in this code I get negative entries in the density matrix. Is anyone aware of some method we can use? The modulus of the eigenvalues does not change the fact that I obtain negative quantum discord, and implementing other approaches to make sure the matrix is always positive semi  definite, do not prevent the quantum discord from become negative.
Here is the code. Any comments are welcome!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the mixed states
p = 0.6
q = 0.4

# Define the pure states
psi3 = (1/np.sqrt(2)) * np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])  # |psi3> = (|00> + |01>)/sqrt(2)
psi4 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])                 # |psi4> = |10>
psi5 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])                 # |psi5> = |11>
psi6 = (np.sqrt(3)/2) * np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]) + (1/2) * np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])  # |psi6> = (sqrt(3)/2)|00> + (1/2)|10>

# Mixed states
rho1 = p * np.outer(psi3, np.conj(psi3)) + (1 - p) * np.outer(psi4, np.conj(psi4))
rho2 = q * np.outer(psi5, np.conj(psi5)) + (1 - q) * np.outer(psi6, np.conj(psi6))

# Define the Hamiltonian and the coupling constant (2 qubits)
H = np.kron(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]), np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]))  # Pauli-X for two qubits

# Define collapse operator C
C = np.kron(np.array([[0, 1], [0, 0]]), np.eye(2))  # Raise first qubit, identity on second qubit

gamma = 1  # Coupling constant

# Function to compute the entropy of a density matrix
def entropy(rho):
    eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(rho)
    eigenvalues = np.maximum(np.real(eigenvalues), 1e-10)  # Avoid log(0) and negative values
    return -np.sum(eigenvalues * np.log(eigenvalues))

# Regularization function to ensure positive semi-definiteness of the density matrix
def regularize_matrix(rho, epsilon=1e-10):
    eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eigh(rho)
    eigvals = np.maximum(eigvals, epsilon)  # Set any negative eigenvalues to epsilon
    return np.dot(eigvecs, np.dot(np.diag(eigvals), eigvecs.T))

# Function to compute the partial trace
def partial_trace(rho, dims, subsystem):
    """
    Compute the partial trace of a density matrix `rho`.

    Args:
        rho (ndarray): Density matrix (shape (d1*d2, d1*d2)).
        dims (tuple): Dimensions of the subsystems (d1, d2).
        subsystem (int): Subsystem to trace out (0 for the first subsystem, 1 for the second).

    Returns:
        ndarray: Reduced density matrix.
    """
    d1, d2 = dims
    rho = rho.reshape((d1, d2, d1, d2))  # Reshape into a 4D tensor
    if subsystem == 0:
        return np.trace(rho, axis1=0, axis2=2)  # Trace out the first subsystem
    elif subsystem == 1:
        return np.trace(rho, axis1=1, axis2=3)  # Trace out the second subsystem
    else:
        raise ValueError("Subsystem must be 0 or 1.")

# Lindblad evolution step (discrete time step)
def lindblad_step(rho, dt, gamma, H, C):
    commutator = -1j * (np.dot(H, rho) - np.dot(rho, H))
    dissipative = gamma * (np.dot(C, np.dot(rho, C.conj().T)) - 0.5 * (np.dot(np.dot(C.conj().T, C), rho) + np.dot(rho, np.dot(C.conj().T, C))))
    rho_new = rho + dt * (commutator + dissipative)
    rho_new = regularize_matrix(rho_new)
    return rho_new

# Calculate the quantum discord
def quantum_discord(rho):
    """
    Compute an approximation of the quantum discord for a 2-qubit system.

    Args:
        rho (ndarray): Full density matrix of the 2-qubit system.

    Returns:
        float: Quantum discord approximation.
    """
    dims = (2, 2)  # Dimensions of the two qubits

    # Partial traces to get reduced density matrices
    rho_A = partial_trace(rho, dims, 1)  # Trace out subsystem B
    rho_B = partial_trace(rho, dims, 0)  # Trace out subsystem A

    # Compute entropies
    S_A = entropy(rho_A)  # Entropy of subsystem A
    S_B = entropy(rho_B)  # Entropy of subsystem B
    S_AB = entropy(rho)   # Entropy of the total system

    # Total correlation: mutual information
    I_A_B = S_A + S_B - S_AB

    # Approximation of classical correlation (simplified but improved)
    classical_corr = max(S_A, S_B)  # Classical correlation: use max(S_A, S_B) as a more reasonable approximation

    return I_A_B - classical_corr

# Time evolution
time_steps = 1000
dt = 0.01
times = np.linspace(0, time_steps * dt, time_steps)

# Store discord values for both mixed states
discord_values_rho1 = []
discord_values_rho2 = []

# Evolve the systems and compute discord at each time step
for t in times:
    rho1 = lindblad_step(rho1, dt, gamma, H, C)
    discord_values_rho1.append(quantum_discord(rho1))
    
    rho2 = lindblad_step(rho2, dt, gamma, H, C)
    discord_values_rho2.append(quantum_discord(rho2))

# Plot the discord over time for the mixed states
plt.plot(times, discord_values_rho1, label=r'$\rho_1$', color='tab:red')
plt.plot(times, discord_values_rho2, label=r'$\rho_2$', color='tab:blue')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Quantum Discord')
plt.title(r'Quantum Discord of the Mixed States $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ Over Time')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

